# ci : handling session in a database without update privilege

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

so for security reasons i want one of my database users only have select/insert privilege ... so everything works fine  but problem is i want to store my sessions in database and it requires UPDATE privilege .

so here are my 2 options :

1 - instead of updating just remove/insert new session with each change  (i dont know how sessions work and what i just said might sound like a joke !  )

2 - use different database account with UPDATE privilege only for sessions

is any of these 2 ways possible ?

i've looked into session.php only reference to database that i could find is this

```
elseif ($driver = config_item('sess_driver'))
{
    $this->_driver = $driver;
}
// Note: BC workaround
elseif (config_item('sess_use_database'))
{
    $this->_driver = 'database';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO will be best to use a different session driver (e.g. Redis or Memcached) for sessions.

This approach will give you more flexibility and speed. All operations are performed in memory, and so reads and writes will be fast.

For more details about session drivers take a look at [Session Library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-library) docs.

Comment: i've also closed all file `create/upload` functions(php) in the server ! so database is my only option